# How do I make a sticky footer with jquerymobile?

Tags: html, mobile, css, jquery-mobile

I want my footer to always be stick to the bottom of the screen, except in the case when there is enough page content to fill the screen In this case, the content should take priority and push the footer off the bottom (so that you have to scroll to see it).

Here is an example of desired behavior:
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

To be clear, I know about [fixed toolbars in JQM](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html), they are not what I want because they take up valuable screen space when there is a lot of content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I have come is the following CSS rule:

```
[data-role=footer] {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you know a better way, please post an answer!

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try **Fixed Full screen or non-full screen but fixed Header and footer** in JqMobile...

In jqMobile, this feature is added and is the **most vibrant feature** in it for webapp developers..

Take a look at it..

[Fixed toolbars : JqMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html)

Also you can apply custom css for the space issue by adding classes...

Answer (score 0):

My best solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("html, body, .ui-page").height($(window).height());
}
```

Hope this helps.